# JQuery/Mootools offset returns null

Tags: jquery, null, mootools, offset

i am using jQuery and mootools librarys and i have this error

```
TypeError: offset is null

 [Parar en este error]  
 if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
```

this is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-styles.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/horizontal.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function(jQuery){

        var offset = jQuery("#bichito").offset();
        var topPadding = 200;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                jQuery("#bichito").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: jQuery(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                jQuery("#bichito").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mootools-1.2-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/excanvas-compressed.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/pngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mocha.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $$('.comprar').each(function(btnCompra) {
                    btnCompra.addEvent('click',function(event){
```

.
.
.
there are more mootols functions.
If i use only the jquery code it works, the same with mootools functions but both no.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this version of mootools is too old and simply should not be used, it also does not play 'nice' with other libs. the oldest you can get away with using is 1.2.6 and even that I wouldn't recommend. 1.4.5 or don't bother.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar, i try this and doesn´t work.

Comment: i have fixed it, i put the jquery code at final.

Comment: Actually Mootools has always played relatively nice with other frameworks (no aggressive claim of the `$` function), but it could break internally. It was later extended to be more $-agnostic internally to play even nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `offset()` method returns `undefined` if it is called on empty collection.
It seems that you're running your jQuery code before DOM is loaded and your `jQuery("#bichito")` element does not exist at that moment.

You can fix your code like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jQuery){ // <-- do you really need closure here?
    jQuery(function(){ // <-- wait DOM ready

        var offset = jQuery("#bichito").offset();
        var topPadding = 200;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                jQuery("#bichito").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: jQuery(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                jQuery("#bichito").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```